# how to import .doc to MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I need to import .doc to MySQL

.doc data are line bye line. like this

[image]

I need to import all this data to MySQL

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if there is something like import doc in MySql.

But you can create php file / java program to parse the .doc/.txt file and then save to database.

I think that is the best solution.